# How to simplify this code?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a simple code:

```
results = mongo.group(                                                                               
        key = [ 'test','id' ],
        ....
    )
    temp_hash = {}
    for result in results:
        if temp_hash.has_key(result['test']):
            temp_hash[result['test']] = int(temp_hash[result['test']]) + 1
        else:
            temp_hash[result['test']] = 1
```

How to simplify this code using only mongodb logic ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `gcount` sample at
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Group. For example, you can do something like:

```py
result = coll.group(['test'], 
                    None, 
                    { count : 0 }, 
                    'function(obj, prev) {prev.count++;}')
```